# Color of badge numbers

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

It might be a hint that I have OCD, but this is really bugging me. The number to the right of the gold dot is a slightly different color:

[image: screenshot of top bar showing number of badges, gold badge is magnified]

Please use less different colors (or at least the same brightness) for the badge numbers and dots or use a more contrasting color for the number.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't for effect? Also, generally, the number after the badge icon is black. Unless you are viewing your own badges.

Comment: There might be reasons, but nevertheless it is distracting me.

Comment: *laughs* I cannot really say anything cause I have OCD to but I guess I will have to agree with you on this one.

Comment: Interesting enough the other badge-types also have different colors for the dot and the number - but those seem similar enough.

Comment: Making it completely Yellow will be impossible to read.

Comment: I hadn't noticed this until now. Thanks a lot... ;-)

Comment: Everything was completely fine until you came along and made me aware of this, now it won't go away :'(

Comment: #goldbadgeproblems

Comment: There are about 5 different oranges being used on the site too. Top bar horizontal line is `#f48024`, tab tops and page number backgrounds are `#f69c55`, the review badge count is `#da670b`, badge progress bar backgrounds are `#ffcc00`, chat room link colors are `#dd6205`... there are probably more. /OCD rant

Comment: What tool have u used to get a zoom like this one?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Eyedropper)

Answer (score 39):

I believe it's darker for one simple reason: if it wasn't it would be really hard to read.

> [image]

[Contrast Ratio](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%23FFCC01-on-%23FAFAFB) confirms this fact as well, although the [current color](http://leaverou.github.io/contrast-ratio/#%23cda400-on-%23FAFAFB) doesn't seem to pass either. If they did anything I personally would like to see the text darkened even more.

Comment: As I write in the question, more contrasting colors (e.g., a darker color or even black numbers) would be fine too.

Comment: Why are they even colored, such small numbers should just be black, if only one of them is black, it dosen't make sens : all black, or keep them like that

Comment: A solution would be to make the badge itself a bit darker too.

Comment: Simple switching back to a dark navbar would solve so much problems...

Answer (score 23):

Good observation!

I think this is due to a UI design guideline which says that if you want two images to seem like the same color, you need to assign the image with less area with a darker color, to make it "seem like" it has the same color as the other image.

If the two images have the exact same color, then the image with less area will actually seem lighter.

It's all subtle optical illusions.

Comment: I agree with @yellowantphil. The "gold" colors appear just different enough that my brain keeps wondering "Are they different? Or are they the same?". Since users should focus on content and not the design, that's a problem.

Comment: Can you post links to the guidelines? I would really like to know more about these stuff!

Comment: I tried to find it but couldn't because I can't remember where I read it. ;)

Answer (score 20):

This is intriguing, and I agree that I had never noticed this before either. It is clearly intentional because it is true for all three badge levels, though the other two seem to balance better (as mention in @Blip's [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344232/2966222) )

I used "Inspect Element" to look at the css governing the colors. Here are the six colors used:

[image]

and in table format:

```
=======  ======  =======
Element  Level   Color  
=======  ======  =======
Badge    Gold    #FFCC01
Text     Gold    #cda400
Badge    Silver  #B4B8BC
Text     Silver  #8c9298
Badge    Bronze  #D1A684
Text     Bronze  #c38b5f
=======  ======  =======
```

It is interesting to note that even the *style* of the hex colors differs (with uppercase for the badges and lower case for the text). Given that the other (Silver and Bronze) badges don't stand out as distinct, it is just the Gold pair that needs to be tweeked (either badge darker or text lighter, or both).

Comment: Arrrgh! I hate it when people use 01 for a color channel!

Comment: @MrLister: That is literally the worst.

Comment: @MrLister Surely it's worse to mix upper and lower case letters when writing out hex values?! Arrrgh!

Comment: @DavidG Well, in this case at least they did it in a consistent manner. The badge colors are all in uppercase, while the derived text colors are all lowercase.

Comment: I'd guess that the lowercase color is calculated by something like a sass function e.g. `darken(hex, amount)`