# Stack Overflow badge colours are too small and indistinct

Tags: bug, badges, accessibility, colorblind

This post has been triggered by me receiving the Caucus badge and being unable to tell if it is silver or bronze no matter how hard I stare at it.

[image]

I am quite happy to admit that I have poor colour vision, and am certainly not alone in this, as [colour blindness](http://www.colourblindawareness.org/) affects 8% of men and 0.5% of women. Obviously this may seem trivial to some, but as badges are part of the Stack Exchange experience, they should be accessible.

I reviewed how Stack Overflow compares to other Stack Exchange network sites in this regard.

[image][image]

In either light mode or dark mode, my eyes tell me that there are two very similar badges, which I cannot clearly distinguish, and a gold one. All we have to distinguish them by is a tiny dot of [colour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344287/7508700), which in the case of bronze and silver which have roughly similar [contrast ratio](https://contrast-ratio.com/#%23b4b8bc-on-%23d1a684) of 1.1.

My next question was whether this was the case on other sites, so I checked a few:

[**Cross Validated**](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/badges)
Larger areas of colour, and a better [contrast ratio](https://contrast-ratio.com/#%23c5c5c5-on-%23e57d26) of 1.6 means I can easily tell them apart.
[image]

[**Raspberry Pi**](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)
Slightly larger area but with a black centre. The slightly larger size and better [contrast ratio](https://contrast-ratio.com/#%23c5c5c5-on-%23cc9966) of 1.46 means I can distinguish them, but only just.
[image]

[**Computer Science**](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/badges)
Similar colours and contrast ratio, but, with the great feature that they're different shapes, so easily distinguished.
[image]

[**Sci Fi**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)
Same colours as Raspberry Pi but again, larger images makes them somewhat easier to distinguish.
[image]

Judging from the brief selection above, it seems straightforward to make badges that are styled to have a larger image, colours with better contrast ratios, different images per badge, or a combination of the three. Currently of the brief review of sites I frequent, Stack Overflow has the smallest, uniform dots, with the least contrasting colours.

Could this be reviewed so that those of us with colour disabilities or weaker vision can tell them apart. Nice large areas of colour are much easier to distinguish. For example, this is much easier to distinguish (in light mode at least...):
[image]
[image]

Comment: ngl, this somewhat surprised me, I've always considered the badge colours extremely distinct... the more you know ^^"

Comment: @Nick Just the same as 90+% of people can do a colourblindness test and see page after page of numbers, whilst I can clearly see about half of them and just a morass of coloured dots on the other half. It doesn't help that colour-blindness comes in quite a wide range of deficiencies, but definitely small areas of colour (like reading resistor colour codes) is very hard for me.

Comment: Does the CSS `.badge1, .badge2, .badge3 { transform: scale(1.4); }` give something close to your desire? You can test by entering `$(document.documentElement).append('<style type="text/css">.badge1, .badge2, .badge3 { transform: scale(1.4); }</style>');` in the console. Past a `scale` of about `1.4`, you really need to increase the `margin-right` from its current `3px`. Going to `4px` makes up to about a `scale` of `1.8` OK: `$(document.documentElement).append('<style type="text/css">.badge1, .badge2, .badge3 { transform: scale(1.8); margin-right:4px}</style>');`

Comment: @Makyen To be honest, I've been squinting at tiny patches of a colour for a while, just compiling this question, so now might not be the right time to answer that. Larger is definitely better than smaller, but making the contrast more dissimilar between the two colours would be much better. I only can tell you what I think though. Would be great to get some feedback from other colourblind users as they might have completely different observations.

Comment: I can never tell the bronze and gold badge apart. Their color looks the same to me

Comment: Not to mention the black on dark gray background.